# remove scrolling from parent page

Tags: html, css

I have a tall form inside a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/8qxwLnd7/

```
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <form>
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        ..
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The height of the form is bigger than the page so I get a scroller on the whole page:

[image]

how can I get the scroller to be inside the form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a height on the html and body, set the overflow to hidden on them, and then set an overflow on the form container you should get what you want:

```css
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
}
.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
}
html,body {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
    <form>
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
        <label class="item">Lbl1:</label>
        <input class="item" type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```